# how can i substract time dates in django to gate the age of a post?

Tags: python, django

i want to display the age of video like "this video uploaded 2 days ago",
"3 weeks and so on"  i have tried this  but not working

```py
#this is not working !!

from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime


class Video(models.Model):
    video_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='media')
    video_detail = models.TextField(blank=True)
    video_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def age_of_video(self):
        return datetime.now() - self.pub_date

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

in template

```
{% for video in all_videos %}

    {{ video.age_of_video}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Django's [humanuze](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/humanize/#module-django.contrib.humanize) utils you can use [**`naturaltime`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/humanize/#naturaltime) tag

```
{% load humanize %}

{% for video in all_videos %}
    {{ video.pub_date|naturaltime }}
{% endfor %}
```

**NOTE:** To activate these filters, add **`'django.contrib.humanize'`** to your **`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting

Comment: Woow thatk you my friend i could have voted 100 times   on ur answ it worked thank you so much for ur time